# PHP How do i copy from an array to another array restricting null or empty

Tags: php

so i have a large array with lots of options, all for cars, so mileage and sound and this and that
now lets say my client doesnt provide a mileage, before i send this array to my function i wanna make sure each element is not empty, those who are not get placed in a new array that will get sented for sql insertion

here is my array:

```
Array ( [year] => select [make] => Buick [model] => [engine] => [mileage] => [price] => [vin] => [att1] => [att2] => [att3] => [att4] => [bodystyle] => [fuel] => [hp] => [cyl] => Select [enginesize] => L [transmission] => [shifts] => [od] => [sound] => [gps] => [sound_system] => [sradio] => [tachometer] => [clock] => [trip] => [eweather] => [digitalboard] => [drive] => [fxf] => [cruisecontrol] => [tiltsteering] => [ac] => [removabletop] => [keyless] => [airbags] => [alloy] => [trunkantitrap] => [ewindows] => [emirrors] => [eseat] => [elocks] => [antitheft] => [ledheadlights] => )
```

so how can i loop through this, if its not empty add it on a new array also an associative one gathering name and value

sorry im a bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach($my_arr as $key => $value) {
    if($value != '' && $value != NULL )
         $new_arr[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: remove the quotes around `NULL`, or else you are comparing to a string instead of comparing to the `null` value. BTW, using `$value != ''` will work for `null` too

Answer (score 4):

You can remove empty values from an array with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$arr = ['foo' => null, 'bar' => 'not null'];
$filtered = array_filter($arr); // contains just "bar" => "not null"
```

However, note that this will remove all values that compare equal to boolean `false`. [Among other values](http://gr2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), this includes the empty string, the string `"0"` and the integer `0`. If you do not want to remove these values, you will have to provide a custom callback to `array_filter`. For example, to only remove `null` values:

```
$arr = ['foo' => null, 'bar' => '0'];
$filtered = array_filter($arr, function($o) { return $o !== null; });
```

Comment: it knows filtered will be an array? i dont need brackets like `$filtered[]`  ??

Comment: @uillkk: Yes. But please try the code yourself and read the documentation before using it.